# What entanglement measures are known to satisfy entanglement monogamy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer

As the title says, what entanglement measures are known to satisfy the entanglement monogamy principle?

Im specially interested in those entanglement measures that apply to mixed states.

Comment: What is the "entanglement monogamy principle"?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I meant monogamy of entanglement. Should I edit that?

Comment: Sure, but without stating clearly what you mean by that (quantitatively), I can probably bend the notion of monogamy so that it fits any entanglement measure.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I guess I mean then: given an entanglement measure $E(\rho_{A|B})$ that measures the entanglement between two bipartitons $A$ and $B$ of a system described by $\rho$ I understand as monogamy of entanglement the following inequality $$E(\rho_{A|B})+E(\rho_{A|C}) \leq E(\rho_{A|BC}),$$ where $C$ is a third partition. Having said that I'm interested in what you mean with you can probably bend the notion of monogamy to fit any entanglement measure :)

Comment: "The more parties you share the entanglement with, the less entangled you are with each party"

Comment: @NorbertSchuch so any entanglement bipartite measure satisfies the monogamy of entanglement principle in some way. Furthermore I guess that it also takes a form similar to the previous equation in my previous comment no?